# Picasso image in Collapsing Toolbar layout ONLY shows in landscape mode

Tags: android, picasso, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

An image loaded with Picasso appears only in landscape mode of the app, never in portrait.

I have a CoordinatorLayout with AppBar and CollapsingToolbarLayout set up in one of my activities. The setup is one of AndroidStudio's auto-generated ones.

I have added an ImageView to the CollapsingToolbarLayout and am loading an image into it in onCreate. I can only see the image in that view if the phone is in landscape mode.

Code:

xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_detail_movie" />
```

activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_movie);

    poster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.poster);
    String url = <posterUrl>
    Picasso.with(this).load(url).fit().into(poster);
}
```

Comment: use `.centerCrop()` also

Comment: try setting imageview a specific height

Comment: Neither suggestion made a difference to the not-in-portrait issues

Answer (score -1):

You have to set your imageview to a specific height and width.